# convert quadratic graph to linear using logarithmic scale

Tags: matlab, math, plot, logarithm, oxyplot

I have to draw a quadratic plot (something like y=a*x^2). I wonder is there anyway to find a logarithmical scale for x or y axis to convert this plot to linear form?


for example lets imagine we have a plot like this:

[image: img]


I want the final plot be something like this by changing the x or y axis to logarithmical scale. I wonder if this is possible theoretically and the answer is yes how can I find the base value of logarithmical scale.

[image: img]

Comment: @MatteoV Not true. See my answer - a plot of `y=ax^b` with log scaling on both axes is a straight line.

Comment: @DanPollard I stand corrected!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what the other answers are going on about here - you're right that if you plot a graph like `y = ax^2` with logarithmic scaling on both axes, you'll see a straight line. For example, I just ran

```
x = 0:0.1:5;
y = x.^2;
plot(x, y)
set(gca, 'xscale', 'log')
set(gca, 'yscale', 'log')
```

in Matlab and the result is a straight line.
Alternatively, you could take the logarithm of the values and plot them,

```
plot(log(x), log(y))
```

with a linear axis scale. In this case the gradient of the line will be the power of your equation (for a quadratic like this, 2) and the y-intercept will be the constant `log(a)`. This is because

```
y = ax^b
log(y) = log(ax^b)
log(y) = log(a) + log(x^b)
log(y) = log(a) + b*log(x).
```

The base of your logarithm doesn't matter, as long as you know what it is. For these sorts of problems it's common to use the natural logarithm, `log` in Matlab. `log10` or `log2` also work.

Note that these methods only work when `x` and `y` are both positive.

Comment: There's also `loglog`, which automatically sets a logarithmic scale in both axes